# Shortcut to Windows Drive Breaks After Reboot

Tags: dual-boot, mount

I've got a dual-boot Ubuntu/Win7 system. Windows and Ubuntu each have their own HD. I like to store many files on the Windows volume because it's larger.

In Ubuntu, the Windows volume is named 'OS' and appears as an item on my launcher. It's path is /media/[name]/OS/ .

I can make a shortcut to, say, /media/[name]/OS/users/userx/Users/ and put it on my desktop in Ubuntu. It works as long I don't reboot. After I reboot, I get an error "This link cannot be used because its target “/media/userx/OS/Users” doesn't exist".

I tried adding # [UUID] ntfs auto 0 0 to /etc/fstab but that doesn't help. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Linux. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that line from:

```
UUID=[UUID here] ntfs auto 0 0
```

to:

```
UUID=[UUID here] /media/userx/OS ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Plus, make sure the directory is actually there with:

```
sudo mkdir /media/userx/OS && sudo chown -R $USER /media/userx/OS
```

(You'll have to change all these directory names to the correct ones).

Comment: I followed these directions, but the link is still broken after reboot. Under the 'devices' column in Nautilus, an eject icon appears next to the HD's name, even though the Win7 HD is wired to my motherboard. Could the system seeing the HD as a 'removable device' be part of my problem?

Comment: Are you still receiving the same error message? An eject icon is normal. It indicates whether the volume is mounted or not. If the volume is mounted, then it has the icon and it is accessible; if it isn't mounted, then it doesn't have the icon and it isn't accessible.

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error message: path does not exist.

Comment: This is a noob question, but: In my fstab, each entry is preceded by a # (for example `code # swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=5d3fede8-7842-4759-b78c-24ed79c29a67 none            swap    sw              0       0` ). I'm assuming that I need to put a # before I begin a new entry for the HD I am trying to link to.  If I neglect to place a new # before the additional entry, I get an error on boot, saying that /media/userx/OS is not ready to mount. This is normal, right?

Comment: @DualBooty No question is a noob question because noobs don't ask questions. It is *not* normal that you should have a `#` before any line in your `/etc/fstab` file *except* if you want the system to ignore that line. That is why the human-readable lines of text are thus "commented out". Do post your /etc/fstab file so we can see exactly what is wrong with it. The Ubuntu pastebin is a good place to upload it (paste.ubuntu.com). Also, the "not ready to mount" message is not normal, that will need to be ironed out, but fixing `/etc/fstab` may likely solve it.

Comment: Alright, contents of my fstab at (including entry for Windows HD "OS") http://paste.ubuntu.com/5960619/

Comment: I'll add that if I leave that last line "commented in", the error I get at start up has three options: wait, skip, or manual recovery. If I choose manual recovery, I get a root shell. I can attempt to exit the shell, but nothing will happen. I didn't attempt to mount the drive while in manual recovery.

Comment: @DualBooty Try changing that last line to simply: `UUID=A67A29207A28EEAD /media/nb-user/OS ntfs auto 0 0` and you'll be set. The problem is you left a `"` at the beginning of the UUID.