# Shortcuts break after a reboot

Tags: shortcuts

How can I create a shortcut of my frequently used software, files and folders? I did some research and found a way which tells I can do so by making a link of a folder and then copy paste the link on the desktop. I did but each time I reboot my PC I see the shortcut is broken! Then I read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328085/shortcut-to-windows-drive-breaks-after-reboot) and followed the ways mentioned in the answers with no luck!

Isn't there any way to create shortcuts like Windows in Linux?

Comment: Does the shortcut point to another partition than the system's root partition?

Comment: most likely this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525498/auto-mount-a-disk-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-bookmark-directory-not-found/525516#525516 a link to another partition that is not automounted. please leave a comment if it isn't.

Comment: @the_Seppi yes. I am using different partitions for different O/S. Ubuntu is in one drive and Windows7 is in another drive. Ubuntu partition file system is ext3 while Windows7 drive's file system is NTFS. So I am trying to access file from different partition and different file system. I guess this is the problem?

Comment: @JacobVlijm sorry guy didn't click on the image. Now seeing... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the drive to which that link belongs (Other than linux partition) is mounted when you restart the PC or when you try to use that link. It mostly happens with window partitions, you are not able to access files from those partitions after system restart. You have to first manually mount them.

Install **NTFS Configuration Tool** and configure the drives which you want to mount on system restart and you will not face the problems of broken links again.